# Como reduzir o tamanho de um variável passada via POST, compactando-a

Tags: php, android, http, post, gzip

Minha aplicação no `Android` pega a `String` envia para o `arquivo.php` que processa os dados.

Logo vi que não conseguiria passar o código em `base64` para o `arquivo.php`.
Preciso de alguma função em `java` que compacte essa **longa** `String` e envie a mesma com um tamanho menor e que o `arquivo.php` possa descompacta-la ao seu estado original para que eu possa manipular os dados.

*Existe alguma forma de fazer isso? Reduzir o código, compactando-o?*

Segue o código que estou a usar.

```
public void postData(String html) {
    URL url = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.0.15/android.php");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .appendQueryParameter("par", html);
    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

    writer.write(query);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();


        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        String output = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.d("httpcliente", "BUSCANDO => [" + output + "]");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            Log.d("JSwa", "Connecting to ["+strings[0]+"]");
            Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
            Log.d("JSwa", "Connected to ["+strings[0]+"]");
            // Get document (HTML page) title
            String title = doc.title();
            Log.d("JSwA", "Title ["+title+"]");
            buffer.append("Title: " + title + "\r\n");

            // Get meta info
            Elements metaElems = doc.select("meta");
            buffer.append("META DATA\r\n");
            for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                String name = metaElem.attr("name");
                String content = metaElem.attr("content");
                buffer.append("name ["+name+"] - content ["+content+"] \r\n");
            }

            Elements topicList = doc.select("h2.topic");
            buffer.append("Topic list\r\n");
            for (Element topic : topicList) {
                String data = topic.text();

                buffer.append("Data [" + data + "] \r\n");
            }



            postData(doc.html());
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        respText.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Só que preciso enviar todo o conteúdo da página ao `php` para que ele consiga processar apenas os dados que desejo, não achei meio de conseguir isso no `Android/Java`, passar varias requisições simultâneas contendo toda a página não geraria uma carga maior? Ao meu ver sim, compactando o post aliviaria mais toda essa carga. Estamos falando de mais de **400** possíveis conexões. Ou não seria necessário tal compressão? Visto que a conexão é rápida, e a resposta também.

Comment: @Florida eu tento criar um exemplo em java no android e te mando

Comment: Tentei não usando o `StandardCharsets`, tentei de muitas formas, a principio seu código não era compatível com a qual o aplicativo é destinado. 4.0 em diante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conforme [@Luídne](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69771/como-reduzir-o-tamanho-de-um-vari%C3%A1vel-passada-via-post-encriptando-a/69778#comment142748_69771) e o [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69771/como-reduzir-o-tamanho-de-um-vari%C3%A1vel-passada-via-post-encriptando-a/69778#comment142827_69771) o erro 414 só ocorre quando os dados são passados pela URL (mesmo que esteja envia POST, ainda você pode enviar dados por GET).

> O erro *414 Pedido-URI Too Long* ocorre quando o URI fornecido foi muito longo para ser processado pelo servidor.
>
> <sup>Fonte: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes</sup>

### Enviando POST para um WebService

Conforme esta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094/1518921), você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
//Suas variáveis POST
String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";

//Envia usando UTF8, altere conforme a necessidade
byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

//Endereço do seu servidor
String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";

int    postDataLength = postData.length;
URL    url            = new URL(request);

HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           

conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );

//Necessário para o envio do POST
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
conn.setUseCaches( false );
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
   wr.write( postData );
}
```

### Comprimindo string

Conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718707/1518921), você pode usar o `GZIPOutputStream` para comprimir/compactar a string:

```
public static byte[] compress(String string) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(string.length());
    GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
    gos.write(string.getBytes());
    gos.close();
    byte[] compressed = os.toByteArray();
    os.close();
    return compressed;
}
```

Se estiver usando o método no arquivo `MainActivity.java` será necessário importar a bibliotecas necessárias, o inicio do MainActivity deve ficar algo como:

```
package ...;

import java.lang.String;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

O uso deve ser algo como:

```
compress('Meu texto');
```

No PHP para você descompactar use [`gzuncompress`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gzuncompress.php) (não testei):

Deve ficar algo como:

```
echo gzuncompress($_POST['data'])
```

Se não funcionar use [`gzdecode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gzdecode.php)

Comment: Me ajudou um pouco, porem não consegui implementar essa função. Me vem a seguinte mensagem `Required: java.lang.String` e `Found:byte[]`. O código está rodando normalmente, não consegui compactar o post, mas é funcional agora. Atualizei para o `HttpURLConnection` pois usava `HttpClient`. Continuarei procurando alternativas compatíveis.

Comment: Atualizei meu comentário. Adicionei, porem não adiantou de nada. Agora só me resta dormir. Ao menos de cabeça fria. Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal.

Comment: Sem sucesso, elas já estão incluídas. Este é o código que estou a suar, caso queira dar uma olhada http://pastebin.com/TQy4Lumz Nota:Minha aplicação usa a versão 4.0.1/4.1 em diante, então notei que algumas coisas como o `StandardCharsets` podem não funcionar. Volto mais tarde para tentar mais.

Comment: Estava usando um método ultrapassado pra conectar, fui procurar saber mais e vi que poderia ter problemas com ele, tive de mudar. Este código achei na **SOen**, achei estranho esse `connect`, mas não tinha usado-o antes, não saberia nunca que eram duas, parece que erraram lá ao postar isso. Vou remove-lo, obrigado por me avisar.